# How to get values of script sql to an object java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two object Person and Student Mapped with hibernate in my database and another object ObjectPR which brings together the two for showing values of two objects in same view

and this is my code java for getting list of ObjectPR

```
StringBuffer sql = new StreingBuffer();  
  sql.append("select p.name as name, s.level as level from 
    person p
        join student s on s.pk_seq = p.fk_student ; ");
    

    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());
    query.addEntity(ObjectPR.class);
   
    List results = query.list();
```

and this is my ObjectPR Class

```
public class ObjectPR {

private String name;
private int level;

//getters setters ...
}
```

and I got this error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: model.ObjectPR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the NEW operator syntax would be adequate here. And also as Student and Person are mapped classes, do not use the native SQL but a normal HQL query:

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();  
sql.append("select NEW model.ObjectPR(p.name as name, s.level as level)
from 
Person p join p.student s");


Query query = getSession().createQuery(sql.toString());

List<ObjectPR> results = query.list();
```

Remeber to add a proper constructro to the ObjectPR class.

**Update**

With native sql you would need to use an additional transformer like this:

```
StringBuffer sql = new StreingBuffer();  
sql.append("select p.name as name, s.level as level from 
person p
    join student s on s.pk_seq = p.fk_student ; ");


SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ObjectPR.class));

List<ObjectPR> results = query.list();
```

Comment: I think it's correct but I wouldn't use HQL I want solution with SQL and thank u very Much

Comment: the Transformers object is from with API ?

Comment: org.hibernate.transform.Transformers